# How does this R syntax work? Selective use of gsub() by [apply() with match()] inside a for loop

Tags: r, syntax, match, apply, gsub

Sometime ago I adapted some code from StackOverflow, but I have been unable to find the original post. The code works fine for my applications, but I don't really 'get' the syntax. (The code overwrites numeric values in the data with specific character strings by matching the numeric data value with the corresponding value in 'new_labels' vector. The matching is column specific.)

Referring to the code below, could someone explain how the [apply] clause is being used to specify where gsub() is making replacements? Or put another way, how does this syntax work? Why does apply affect gsub() here? Better yet, is there an simpler approach to this action?

```
# reproducible example
# fake data           
    dat <- tibble(var1 = c(1,NA, 1,1,1,2,1,NA,1,1),
                  var2 = c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA),
                  var3 = c(2,2,NA,2,NA,1,2,NA,NA,NA),
                  var4 = c(NA,NA,2,NA,2,NA,NA,2,2,2)) 
# names of columns in fake data
variables <- names(dat)
# names of new labels to replace the numeric values
new_labels <- c("elf", "hobbit", "wizard", "ranger")      
# empty list
    llist <- list(ones = data.frame(matrix(ncol=4,nrow=10)),
                  twos = data.frame(matrix(ncol=4,nrow=10)))
    names(llist[[1]]) <- letters[1:length(new_labels)]
    names(llist[[2]]) <- letters[1:length(new_labels)]
# for loops
    for(j in 1:2){   
        for(i in 1:length(new_labels)){
            llist[[j]][, letters[i]] <- gsub(variables[i], new_labels[i], names(dat[,variables[i]]))[apply(dat[,variables[i]], 1, match, x= j)]
    }
        llist[[j]][is.na(llist[[j]])] <- ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of nesting here, but to understand functions, the best way is to run the most nested part in your console and work outwards.

lets assume i = 1 and j = 1

`apply(dat[,variables[i]], 1, match, x= j)` apply is being fed a subset of data, namely "var1" column. match is then being applied to each index of that column, returning a 1 if the value in the index matches x argument and else returns NA.

this vector, lets call it `vec` is then passed to `names(dat[,variables[i]]))[vec]`.

`names(dat[,variables[i]])` seems to just return `variable[i]` so it seems a bit pointless in this example.

`names(dat[,variables[i]]))[vec]` replaces each 1 value in `vec` with the value in `variables[i]`

finally, in `gsub(pattern = variables[i], new_labels[i], new.vec)`
where `new.vec` is `names(dat[,variables[i]]))[vec]`

Comment: Thanks for excellent explanation! I was struggling to make sense of what apply() was doing because I did not recognize that a vector could be passed to gsub() this way. But more than that, when you say the `names(dat[,variables[i]]))`, clause is a bit pointless, does that mean you suspect it could be simplified to just `variables[i]` ? Many, many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I only say that one bit of code may be pointless because from my own trouble shooting in this example it `variable[i]` would work just fine. I did not try to think of a case where `names(dat[,variables[i]])` was necessary, BUT if you did get this code from someone else, then they likely had a reason for coding it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pull it out of the loop and see exactly what is going on.

```
gsub(variables[1], new_labels[1], names(dat[,variables[1]]))[apply(dat[,variables[1]], 1, match, x = 1)]
[1] "elf" NA    "elf" "elf" "elf" NA    "elf" NA    "elf" "elf"
```

Looking at the help for `?apply`: `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)`, where `x` is the column of `dat` we're looping to first, `1` is the margin, `?match` is the function it's applying, and `x = j` is part of the loop for `match`, between `1` and `2` (from the `for(j in 1:2)`). As in, if it finds a match for `1`, replace with a `1`.

```
apply(dat[,variables[1]], 1, match, x = 1)
 [1]  1 NA  1  1  1 NA  1 NA  1  1
```

And the `gsub` substitutes the first `new_labels` name, `(elf)`, for the first `variables` name `(var1)`, and writes it to the matching element of `letters[i]` (`letters[1]` is `a`). So it finds a match in the first `list` element of `llist` (named `ones`) in a column matching `a`.

It repeats this for all `1` values for each label, then for each list element, then for all `2` values, etc. The first row turns into the second.

```
[1]  1    NA   1     1     1    NA     1    NA     1     1
[1] "elf" NA  "elf" "elf" "elf" NA    "elf" NA    "elf" "elf"
```

It's a rather elegant process.

Here is a step-by-step without a loop, so you can see essentially what the loop does.

```
dat2 <- as.data.frame(dat)
names(dat2) <- new_labels
dat2 <- list(dat2, dat2)
dat2[[1]][dat2[[1]] == 2] <- NA
dat2[[2]][dat2[[2]] == 1] <- NA
w1 <- which(dat2[[1]] == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)
w2 <- which(dat2[[2]] == 2, arr.ind = TRUE)
dat2[[1]][w1] <- colnames(dat2[[1]])[w1[,"col"]]
dat2[[2]][w2] <- colnames(dat2[[2]])[w2[,"col"]]
dat2 <- lapply(dat2, function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- "" ; x})

[[1]]
   elf hobbit wizard ranger
1  elf                     
2      hobbit              
3  elf                     
4  elf                     
5  elf                     
6             wizard       
7  elf                     
8      hobbit              
9  elf                     
10 elf                     

[[2]]
   elf hobbit wizard ranger
1             wizard       
2             wizard       
3                    ranger
4             wizard       
5                    ranger
6  elf                     
7             wizard       
8                    ranger
9                    ranger
10                   ranger
```